# Why isn't this second-level eager loading working?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, associations

I have three models, Subrating, Thing, and Category. Subrating belongs_to Thing, and Thing has_many Categories.

I have a list of Subratings, and I'm trying to eager-load the Categories that are associated with the Things that are associated with each Subrating.

This is what I tried:

---

**controller**

```
@subratings = Subrating.all( :include => { :thing => :categories })
```

**view**

```
<% @subratings.sort_by(&:rating).reverse.each do |subrating| %>
  <%= subrating.thing.categories.sort_by(&:thing_count).second.name %>
<% end %>
```

---

But it doesn't solve my n+1 problem. I'm not even sure whether the database is lazy-loading Things or Categories or both, but this is the line that keeps reappearing hundreds of times in my server:

```
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "things" INNER JOIN "category_things" ON "things"."id" = "category_things"."thing_id" WHERE "category_things"."category_id" = $1  [["category_id", 1]]
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

**associations**

```
class Subrating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :thing
end

class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_things
  has_many :categories, :through => :category_things
  has_many :subratings
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_things
  has_many :things, :through => :category_things
end

class CategoryThing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :thing
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should try to call includes on the Model class like:

```
@subratings = Subrating.includes(thing: [:categories])
```

as documented in http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes

although it also should work the way you are trying it, since `.all` is an alias for `.find(:all)` but then i would propose to try:

```
@subratings = Subrating.all( :includes => { :thing => [:categories] })
```

(note that i changed `include` to `includes` and made thing point to an array)

Comment: Both of these queries result in the same N+1 problem. I just keep getting that same line, hundreds of times.

Comment: Never mind, the problem came from the ".sort_by(&:thing_count)".

Answer (score 0):

```
@subratings = Subrating.includes(:thing => :categories)
```

This will also work for you and give you all records of substrings table.